# How to calculate a distance matrix from a diagonal line?

Tags: r, line, point, diagonal, distance-matrix

Consider we have a data frame called **Pred**.

It consists of 1 user per row.

The users are specified by their unique **userID**.

Users can be grouped by the **cluster** they belong to.

Users reported their Confidence and Challenge for a task, this information is saved as **Conf** and **Chall** respectively.

Note that both **Conf** and **Chall** have the same range from i.e., 1-6.

```
cluster   userID      Conf        Chall
1           A           5           3
2           B           3           2
1           C           6           1
1           D           3           4
2           E           2           4
2           F           3           5
1           G           6           2
1           H           5           5
2           I           6           2
2           J           5           4
2           K           1           1
1           L           3           5
1           M           4           4
```

Let's say we make a scatter-plot where **Conf** is on x-axis and **Chall** is on y-axis.

The points where:

```
Conf == Chall
```

would be on the diagonal line which passes through the origin.

Now I am interested in finding the distance of each user from the diagonal line based on their coordinates:

```
(Conf, Chall)
```

Overall, the question deals with finding the distance of points (Conf, Chall) from the line at the diagonal.

**Note**: Please note that I am not interested in plotting the graph. I am interested in calculating a distance vector.

I understand, it is perhaps a very basic question but I have been struggling for the past few days. A simple demo example code would help me understand this problem.

I would appreciate any guidance on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Euclidean distance from a point (x,y) to the diagonal line is given by

```
abs(x - y) / sqrt(2)
```

See, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_an_equation). Thus, you may use

```
(Pred$distance <- abs(Pred$Conf - Pred$Chall) / sqrt(2))
# [1] 1.4142136 0.7071068 3.5355339 0.7071068 1.4142136 1.4142136 2.8284271
# [8] 0.0000000 2.8284271 0.7071068 0.0000000 1.4142136 0.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!
When I run this code on my bigger file, I see some discrepancies. 
As per my understanding the distance should be 0 when the point lies on the diagonal line i.e., when Conf == Chall. 
However, for all the data my distance vector stays non-zero.

Comment: @Sadiaz, no problem. You must be missing something since clearly it should give 0 as in the numerator we have `df$Conf - df$Chall`.